# Parse - Modify PFObject on beforeSave?

Tags: parse-platform

When a use is created in the system I want to create a blank profile for them.
The following code doesn't seem to work, what am I missing?

I'm not seeing any errors in the log, and the profiles gets created successfully.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("User", function(request, response) {
    if (request.object.get("profile") == null) {
        request.object.fetch().then(function(user){
            var Profile = Parse.Object.extend("Profile");
            var profile = new Profile();
            user.set("profile", profile);
            response.success();
        });
    }
    else {
        response.success();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you try "_User"?  I'm pretty sure that's how Parse set's their User class. So like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("_User", function(request, response) {
    if (request.object.get("profile") == null) {
        request.object.fetch().then(function(user){
            var Profile = Parse.Object.extend("Profile");
            var profile = new Profile();
            user.set("profile", profile);
            response.success();
        });
    }
    else {
        response.success();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that solved part of the problem. Now I'm getting Can't serialize an unsaved Parse.Object. It's because when I call fetch the object doesn't exits. I don't want to move the code to afterSave because I want to ensure that a User is never created without a profile

Comment: But that's a different problem I'll accept this as an answer

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a variable like `request.user` or something that contains a ref to the PFUser that made the call, not sure if that would work here.  I've never tried to beforeSave a PFUser.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in this case you'll need to save the profile first:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("_User", function(request, response) {
    if (request.object.get("profile") == null) {
        request.object.fetch().then(function(user){
            var Profile = Parse.Object.extend("Profile");
            var profile = new Profile();
            return profile.save();
        }).then(function(profile) {
            user.set("profile", profile);
            response.success();
        });
    }
    else {
        response.success();
    }
});
```